# How to create a dataset with Huggingface from a list of strings to fine-tune Llama 2 with the transformers library?

Tags: python, dataset, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-datasets, fine-tuning

I have a list of strings and I want to use them to fine tune Llama 2. Every entry of the list contains a couple of sentences.

I need to bring this into the right format to use the Trainer of the transformers library. But I don't seem to find anything online. This should be a really basic problem?

I don't need a validation dataset. Just a way to feed the dataset in to the trainer via

```
trainer = transformers.Trainer(model=model,train_dataset=dataset,... )
```

this is what I have tried:

```
from datasets import Dataset

dataset = Dataset.from_list(list)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me in the end:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(list)

from datasets import Dataset
dataset = Dataset.from_pandas(df.rename(columns={0: "train"}), split="train")
```

and then to tokenize the data:

```
tokenized_dataset = dataset.map(lambda samples: tokenizer(samples["train"]), batched=True)
```